# Contact shadow distortion

Tags: modeling, shaders, lighting, shadows

When I put on my contact shadows in Eevee, there is a distortion that looks like it is trying to replicate a god ray effect for shadows that I don't want.

I added a Vanilla sphere with none of the shaders as well and it still happens

I can provide the file if necessary

please help me!

Contact Shadow Off

[image: without contact shadow]

Contact Shadow On
[image: with contact shadow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact shadows is a screen space effect, which means that it uses only screen rendering information to make the effect, so it is not accurate. Try to reduce **Thickness** here:

[image]

Or try to set up Shadow **bias** instead of using Contact shadows

Comment: thank you, that seemed to have done the trick!